# angular ng-repeat has list items but not displaying parameter {{}} in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I am returning result from api which is
[{name: "ABC", age: 20}, {name: "DEF", age: 25}]

The $scope.names is set to array returned from api. And in browser, it does print 2 rows but each cell in html table row is empty. Why?

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
    <td>{{ name.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ name.age }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the problem is somewhere else because your cose is right. Are you sure you're binding the controller with this view? Do you using the tag `<table>..</table>`, am I right? Try to print in view `{{names | json }}`

Answer (score 0):

in controller you have something like this

```
function CTRL($scope) {
  $scope.names=  [
  {name: "ABC", age: 20}, {name: "DEF", age: 25}];
}
```

this is an array of objects , you need to loop through it as below

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in names">
    <td>{{ value.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ value.age }}</td>
</tr>
```

check the below for demonstration

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller(CTRL); 

function CTRL($scope) {
  $scope.names =  [
  {name: "ABC", age: 20}, {name: "DEF", age: 25}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="CTRL">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in names">
    <td>{{ value.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ value.age }}</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `(key,value) in names` is for interate over object properties. There is no need for using that since this is an array.

Comment: and you can use it to iterate over array of objects as well

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <script
          src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
       <body>
         <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <table>
           <tr>
            <td>{{name of names}}</td>
            <td>{{age of names}}</td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
         <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
            app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
              $scope.names =[{name:"ABC", age: 20}, {name: "DEF", age: 25}]
            });
         </script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the whole (key, value) pair you can do it by only taking the value.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <script
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <body>
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="val in names">
        <td>{{val.name}}</td>
        <td>{{val.age}}</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
     <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
          $scope.names =[{name:"ABC", age: 20}, {name: "DEF", age: 25}]
        });
     </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you code seems workable to me, not sure you binding correctly in the controller

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller(CTRL); 

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.names =  [{name: "ABC", age: 20}, {name: "DEF", age: 25}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
    <td>{{ name.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ name.age }}</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```